# How to add classes to DataTables table wrapper?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

DataTables wraps tables in a `div` having `dataTables_wrapper` as class. Thus, doing:

```html
<table
        id="my-wonderful-list"
        class="table table-dark-gray table-hover w-100"
>
    <thead class="table-dark">
    <tr>
        <th class="border-0">First column</th>
        <th class="border-0">Second column</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

```js
$(function () {
    let wonderfulTable = $('#my-wonderful-list').DataTable({
        // options here
    });
});
```

results in:

```html
<div id="my-wonderful-list_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper dt-bootstrap5 no-footer">
    <table id="my-wonderful-list" class="table table-dark-gray table-hover w-100 dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" style="width: 1202px;">
        <thead class="table-dark">
            <tr>
                <th class="border-0 sorting sorting_desc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="my-wonderful-list" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 194px;" aria-label="First column: activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant" aria-sort="descending">
                    First column
                </th>
                <th class="border-0 sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="my-wonderful-list" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 137px;" aria-label="Second column: activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant">
                    Second column
                </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- table body -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
<div>
```

How can I alter the wrapper classes to add my own to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sWrapper` to specify which classes you want on the wrapper. You need to put it above your DataTable configuration, like so:

```js
$(function () {
    $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sWrapper = "your-custom-class1 your-custom-class2";
    let supportTable = $('#my-wonderful-list').DataTable({
        // options here
    });
});
```

It will result in:

```html
<div id="my-wonderful-list_wrapper" class="your-custom-class1 your-custom-class2 no-footer">
    <table id="my-wonderful-list" class="table table-dark-gray table-hover w-100 dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" style="width: 1202px;">
        <thead class="table-dark">
            <tr>
                <th class="border-0 sorting sorting_desc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="my-wonderful-list" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 194px;" aria-label="First column: activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant" aria-sort="descending">
                    First column
                </th>
                <th class="border-0 sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="support-list" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 137px;" aria-label="Second column: activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant">
                    Second column
                </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- table body -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
<div>
```

Be aware that some classes are removed, in this case `dataTables_wrapper` and `dt-bootstrap5`.